# Add class to li's in a ul according to an array's length through jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<ul class="tickboxes">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
let selected = [];

$(".tickboxes li").each((i, tickbox) => {
  // add the class here
});
```

How can I add class to li's according to the length of `selected` array?

For example, if the length of `selected` array is 3, the first 3 li's should have the `colored_tickbox` class and look like so in the browser:

```
<ul class="tickboxes">
  <li class="colored_tickbox"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li class="colored_tickbox"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li class="colored_tickbox"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Actually, you can just use a number instead of the array. So I can summarize this question to: How can I add class to the first x ones according to x number.

EDIT: 
Once there are, let's say, 3 class added to the first 3 li-s, I also want to remove the class according to the array's length. So once the array is 3, 3 classes get added, and once the array is 2, 1 class gets removed so that 2 li-s would have the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`:lt` selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) is a simple approach

```js
let selected =[1,2,3];

$('.tickboxes li:lt(' + selected.length + ')').addClass('colored_tickbox')
```

```css
.colored_tickbox{ border:1px solid green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tickboxes">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice and simple answer. Thumbs up :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that once there are, let's say, 3 class added to the first 3 li-s, I also want to remove the class according to the array's length. So once the array is 3, 3 classes get added, and once the array is 2, 1 class gets removed so that 2 li-s would have the class.

Comment: Simple enough to create a chain for that also ... `$('.tickboxes li').removeClass('colored_tickbox').filter(':lt(' + selected.length + ')').addClass('colored_tickbox')`

Comment: That was fast! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Numerous other ways to do it... I just chose `:lt` to start with